# Stripe Payment Library Issue with Scala and Play app

Tags: scala, sbt, stripe-payments, playframework-2.3

I have created Scala and Play Framework application and with it I am trying to use Stripe Payment Library. But when I am using I was getting below error:

> Compilation error
>
> object stripe is not a member of package com

I am using versions as below,

1. Scala Version: 2.11.6
2. SBT Version: 0.13.8

I have used Stripe SBT dependency in `build.sbt` as below,

```
"com.stripe"    % "stripe-scala_2.9.1"      % "1.1.2"
```

My `build.sbt` file as below:

```
name := """My App Name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  ws,
  filters,
  "com.typesafe.play"                         %% "play-mailer"            % "3.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.play"                         %% "play-slick"             % "1.1.1",
  "com.typesafe.play"                         %% "play-slick-evolutions"  % "1.1.1",
  "postgresql"                                %  "postgresql"             % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "commons-lang"                              % "commons-lang"            % "2.6",
  "com.stripe"                                % "stripe-scala_2.9.1"      % "1.1.2"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

My controller where it is giving exception:

```
package controllers

import com.stripe
import com.stripe.{Charge, Customer}
import play.api.mvc._
/**
  * Created by Nishan Patel on 28-04-2016.
  */
class PaymentController extends Controller {

  def getPayment = Action { request =>
    val formData = (request.body).asFormUrlEncoded

    val stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    val token = formData.get("stripeToken")(0)

    val customerParams = Map("source" -> token, "description" -> "Customer Rollback Renew req.")

    val customer = Customer.create(customerParams)

    val chargeParams = Map("amount" -> 2000, "currency" -> "usd", "customer" -> customer.id)

    Charge.create(chargeParams);

    Ok
  }

}
```

```html
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'package
.class'.
[error] Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definitio
n for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to s
ee the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incom
patible version of scala.
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'APIReso
urce.class'.
[error] Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definitio
n for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to s
ee the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'APIResource.class' was compiled against an i
ncompatible version of scala.
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Custome
r.class'.
[error] Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definitio
n for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to s
ee the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Customer.class' was compiled against an inco
mpatible version of scala.
[error] missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'Charge.
class'.
[error] Could not access type ScalaObject in package scala,
[error] because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definitio
n for
[error] missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to s
ee the problematic classpath.)
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Charge.class' was compiled against an incomp
atible version of scala.
[error] E:\Nishan\Confidential\My Workspace\MetaForce\app\controllers\PaymentCon
troller.scala:14: stable identifier required, but com.stripe.`package`.apiKey fo
und.
[error]     val stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_xxxxxx";
[error]                ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] application -
```

Everything looks good but don't know why am I getting this compilation issue.

Comment: It looks to me like that library is very outdated, last being updated in 2012.  This seems to be what you would want to use: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.stripe/stripe-java

Comment: To expand on that, check out https://stripe.com/docs/libraries - looks like they're not maintaining a separate scala library (and I have no idea why they would).

Comment: @childofsoong I used that too but having the same issue. So with java sbt plugin I'm also having the same issue.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest posting a question about that one, since it's the one their web site lists and it's actually been updated this year, rather than four years ago.  It's probably a syntax error.  Also, I just realized that the scala one is on that page, but it's as a 'community-supported library' (and the github repo for it is similarly outdated)

Comment: In addition to what @childofsoong said, you should be able to include Stripe's Java API by adding `libraryDependencies += "com.stripe" % "stripe-java" % "2.3.0"` to your `build.sbt`, then going from there.

Comment: @Eric I tried with java api as well but still having the same issue. I used latest Java API released this year 2016 of version 2.4.0.

Comment: Using a `*_2.9.1` dependency with a Scala 2.11 project is generally a bad idea

Comment: @cchantep you are right but stripe's Scala library is too old and I was even getting exception with latest Java version sbt so I tried with old sbt setting but with all options it was not working.

Comment: Post your complete `build.sbt` file, please. Also, post the code where the compilation problem is happening.

Comment: Hi @marcospereira please have a look, I have modified my post with sbt and controller file. I was getting error in controller on browser "object stripe is not a member of package com".

Comment: The `val stripe.apiKey` is wrong. Maybe you want just `stripe.apiKey` instead (without the `val`)? From where were you expecting `stripe` to come from?

Comment: @marcospereira, I tried that way also, but no luck.. it is throwing same exception.

Comment: It is not an exception. It is a compilation problem. I don't know Stripe Java client, but have you tried to convert [theirs example](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java#usage) to scala?

Comment: @marcospereira you are right it is compilation problem but it is not even working with Java library. I was getting same  compilation issue with Java so I can not test any code which contains stripe classes reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, based on the error message, you are having problems with incompatible versions of Scala. Basically what @cchantep told you at the comments. Keep in mind that Scala 2.9.x is not binary compatible with Scala 2.11.x and you are just asking from problems when mixing both versions.

Remove the following line of your `build.sbt` file:

```
"com.stripe" % "stripe-scala_2.9.1" % "1.1.2"
```

And add the updated and maintained version of the client provided by Stripe:

```
"com.stripe" % "stripe-java" % "2.4.0"
```

After that, you need to rewrite your code to use this new client. Here is an example based on [Stripe docs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java#usage) and also your code:

```
def getPayment = Action { request =>
  val requestOptions = new RequestOptionsBuilder()
    .setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .build()

  val formData = (request.body).asFormUrlEncoded
  val token = formData.get("stripeToken")(0)
  val customerParams = Map("source" -> token, "description" -> "Customer Rollback Renew req.")

  val customer = Customer.create(customerParams)

  val chargeParams = Map("amount" -> 2000, "currency" -> "usd", "customer" -> customer.id)

  Charge.create(chargeParams, requestOptions);

  Ok
}
```

But... keep in mind that this code is just a start point and it have problems (it is blocking, per instance).

Comment: Thanks @marcospereira, above solution works for me. Thanks a lot..!